# Explanation for the output of the code

Tags: c, pointers, return, lifetime, fflush

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *call();
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr=call();
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
int * call()
{
    int x=25;
    ++x;
    return &x;
}
```

The output for this code is 0. I was expecting 26.
Can someone please explain the reason?
And what should I be doing to get 26?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is UB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: That is the lesser of the problems with that code. It is sprikeled with UB.

Comment: what does UB mean?

Comment: UB : Undefined Behavior

Comment: Some explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: @drew Can you pls explain your intention to use `fflush()` in your code??
I am confused, did not get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create this function and call it a function frame is pushed into the stack having a space for a int variable declared there. Now you increase the value and try to return address of that. Now function ends and stack frame is deleted. You are trying to read it. It will return something random. Ah not random in its sense but  what it returns is not defined. You get 0 ..may get 1 or 23 or 128749 or -7364184 sometimes.

To get 26 you might want to use something from heap.(or declare an array which will be alive long enough).
Allocate memory big enough to hold an integer variable. Then manipulate it. Return pointer to that . You will see what you want to see.

Note: It's undefined behavior.... it may return something else when you run at different time or different machine. :)

This heap and stack that I mentioned here are implementation specific. By heap I mean the dynamic memory which we allocate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, from `int * call()`, you're returning the address of a local variable, which becomes invalid after the function has finished execution. Using the return value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should either

- take a pointer, allocate memory using memory allocator functions like `malloc()` and family and then return the pointer.
- make use of a `static` variable whole lifetime is throughout the program execution.

That said, do not use `fflush(stdin)`, as it invokes undefined behaviour. Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.5.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `fflush()` on `stdin`, it has undefined behaviour for input streams. [You can Read about it here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

Returning the address of a local variable, which becomes invalid after the function has finished execution will result in Undefined Behaviour.

In expectation of answer, I removed `fflush(stdin)` and got output `26` on both Windows and GCC 4.1.2 compilers.

As commented by @Anjaneyulu, it may be compiler dependent too, but here's screenshot from my test on windows.

[image]

Comment: I did not get 26 by removing fflush.

Comment: @drew added screenshot for reference.

Comment: @akhilesh1988 once the function returns its stack frame destroys and produces undefined behavior and it is compiler dependent too

Comment: @Anjaneyulu I got same result on GCC 4.1.2 compiler also after removing `fflush()`, wondering how's that???
But theoretically, I do agree, returning address of Local Variable might result in Undefined Behaviour.